# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am having some trouble getting my search query to work. I get this error.

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Here's my code.

```
<?php
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `character` WHERE `name` LIKE :search  OR `play` LIKE :search";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $query->execute(array(':search' => strip_tags($_POST['search'])));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row){
            $name = $row['name'];
            $gender = $row['gender'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>
            <td>". $name ."</td>
            <td>". $gender ."</td>
                <td><a href='characterbio.php?id=". $id ."'>". $name ."'s Bio Page</a></td>
                </tr>";
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
     die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Might want to throw some wildcard characters around those `LIKE` conditions, eg `field LIKE CONCAT('%', :param, '%')`. Also, `strip_tags()` makes very little sense in the context you're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [`PDO::Prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to
>   pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You
>   cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in
>   a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

So either turn emulation mode on

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);
```

or change to -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `character` WHERE `name` LIKE :search1  OR `play` LIKE :search2";
$query = $db->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(array(':search1' => strip_tags($_POST['search']),':search2' => strip_tags($_POST['search'])));
```

Also, since you are using `LIKE` in your query, you will want to add wildcards `%` to your values

```
$query->execute(array(':search1' => "%".strip_tags($_POST['search'])."%",':search2' => "%".strip_tags($_POST['search'])."%"));
```